# Python 3 multiprocessing error

Tags: python-3.x, join, process, fork, spawn

I'm trying to run this code taken form python doc
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

but here what I get:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 15744
process id: 7344
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\<stdin>'
```

what am I doing wrong? I use python 3.6.1.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code... it may be how you are running it. Python is trying to import your script but its named 'C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\<stdin>'.... are you running from IDLE?

Comment: Thanks . Tried to run it from concole and it works as it should.I was running it from vim with :w !python command before.

Comment: yeah, that explains it. On Windows, python needs to re-execute the script and it couldn't figure out what it was.